# org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private int com.h2test.demo.Customer.id]

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Faced this issue below when trying to use Hibernate with SpringBoot. (I'm using embedded H2 DB).
Separately it works perfect. But when I want to make CRUD operation inside of my SpringBoot application I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String com.h2test.demo.Customer.address] by reflection for persistent property [com.h2test.demo.Customer#address] : ID: 0
First Name: First Name
Last Name: Last Name
BirthDate: 01.01.01
Address: Russia
at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:43)
at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.getForInsert(GetterFieldImpl.java:58)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValuesToInsert(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:522)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValuesToInsert(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:241)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getPropertyValuesToInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4743)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:251)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:679)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:671)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:666)
at com.h2test.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:16)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field com.h2test.demo.Customer.address to com.h2test.demo.Customer
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:39)
... 21 more
```

And here is my **SpringBoot Application**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().addAnnotatedClass(Customer.class).configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.save(new Customer("First Name","Last Name","01.01.01","Russia"));
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is **`Customer` Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "customer_id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "fname")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "lname")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "birthDate")
private String birthDate;

@Column(name = "address")
private String address;

public Customer() {

}

public Customer(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String birthDate, String address) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
    this.address = address;
    this.id = id;
}

public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String birthDate, String address) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
    this.address = address;
}

public void setId() {this.id = id;}
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public String getBirthDate() {
    return birthDate;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public void setBirthDate(String birthDate) {
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ID: " + getId() + "\n" +
            "First Name: " + getFirstName() + "\n" +
            "Last Name: " + getLastName() + "\n" +
            "BirthDate: " + getBirthDate() + "\n" +
            "Address: " + getAddress();
}


}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <mapping class="com.h2test.demo.Customer"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**hibernate.properties**

```
hibernate.connection.driver=org.h2.Driver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
hibernate.connection.user=sa
hibernate.connection.password=""
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

**application.properties is empty**

I read a lot about this topic, but I couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: I think this will give you a hint, **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field com.h2test.demo.Customer.address to com.h2test.demo.Customer**

Comment: @manuka_m
yes, I tried to find the reason of that message, but no success

Comment: @manuka_m did you managed to solve this ?